# Does this require a dynamic form or not?

Tags: django

This is my forms.py code

```
    class register(forms.Form):
        list = services.objects.all()
        for item in list:
            item.name = forms.BooleanField()
```

The model services is

```
    class services(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

This is how i use above form in my view

```
    form = register()
    return render_to_response("main.html",{'html_form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but i get a blank html( no checkboxes !).
Do I need a dynamic form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/)

```
class Register(forms.form):

    item = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=services.objects.all(),
                                  default=None,
                                  widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Comment: This code produces a dropdown list. I need a checkbox(BooleanField) array, one for each service so that as many services can be selected as i want !  Do i need a Dynamic form for such a simple thing ?

Comment: That will get you a series of checkboxes.